# Prove that for $a>1$ and $b>0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^{n-1}≤b<a^n$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that for $a>1$ and $b>0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^{n-1}≤b<a^n$

In order to prove this we use the **Archimedean Property** for numbers $\ln(a)$ and $\ln(b)$.
I know how to prove this but what I don't understand is why a must be greater than 1 why a can't be any value between $0$ and $1$?
If anyone can answer this question I would really appreciate it.Thank you!

Comment: It can be: for $c\in (0,1)$ just use $a = 1/c$ and $c^n = a^{-n}$.

Comment: If $0 < a < 1$ you get the opposite result $a^{n} < b \le a^{n+1}$.  Another why of stating the desired result is.  For any $a > 0; a\ne 1$ there is an integer $n$ so that $b$ is between $a^n$ inclusive and $a^{n+1}$ exclusive.  If $a>1$ then $a^n$ is increasing and if $a < 1$ then $a^n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that there is an integer $n$ such that $a^{n-1}\leqslant b<a^n$. I suppose that what you did was to replace this inequality with $$(n-1)\ln(a)\leqslant\ln(b)<n\ln(a)\tag1$$ and then you applied the Archimedian property, right?! More precisely, you deduced from that property that there is a $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n-1\leqslant\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}<n$. But, if $a\in(0,1)$, then this is *not* equivalent to $(1)$ because then $\ln a<0$ and therefore what you get after dividing by $\ln a$ is$$n-1\geqslant\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}>n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $a<1$ would require that you reverse the inequality symbols in $$a^{n-1}≤b<a^n$$ so instead you be tasked with proving that there is an $n$ such that $$a^{n-1}\geq b>a^n$$ Excluding the possibility is merely a convenience which makes the problem shorter to state and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a generally easier way to approach the problem. Given any $x \in (0,1)$, we can also say that $x^n = {(\frac{1}{x})}^{-n}$ (bearing in mind that $n$ can also be negative) and so considering this, we do not have to worry about the sign of the logarithm, as $x>1$. So you are right in so far as $a$ not needing to be greater than $1$, but the proof will cover the other case regardless.

Answer (score 0):

$a\gt 1$ ensures  $\ln a\gt 0 $ so you can use the Archimedean property. ..

Answer (score 0):

Others have already stated why $a>1$ is not a loss of generality. Let me rephrase it somewhat, what is essential here is that you are considering $n\in\mathbb Z$. For example, if you only considered $n\in\mathbb N_0$, then for $a>1$, intervals $I_n = [a^n,a^{n+1})$ only cover $[1,+\infty)$ and for $0<a<1$, intervals $J_n = [a^{n+1},a^n)$ cover $(0,1)$. But, since you allow negative exponents, along with identity $a^{-n} = \frac 1{a^n}$ lets you cover both $(0,1)$ and $[1,+\infty)$, and it really doesn't matter whether you work with $a>1$ or $a<1$, because you can easily switch between the two.

So, how could one go about making the above into a proof. First of all, notice that Archimedean property gives you both $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n= +\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{-n}= 0$.$^{[1]}$ This gives you the following:

$$\bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty} [a^n, a^{n+1}) = \bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty} [1, a^{n+1}) = [1,+\infty),$$

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} [a^{-n}, a^{-n+1}) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} [a^{-n}, 1) = (0,1).$$

If you don't like that approach, you can do casework $b\geq 1$ and $b<1$. In the first case define $n = \min\{m\in\mathbb N_0\mid a^m> b\}$ and in the second $n = -\min\{m\in\mathbb N_0\mid \frac 1{a^{m+1}} \leq b\},$ combining Archimeddean property and well-ordering of $\mathbb N_0$.

---

$[1]$ This is where we do use the fact that $a>1$, otherwise the limits would be switched and if you just said that $a>0$, $a\neq 1$, you would have to do a casework.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more thorough and all encompassing result wold be stated as such:

Fore any $a > 1$ then $a^n$ is increasing.  (If $m > n; m,n \in \mathbb Z$ then $a^m > a^n$).  If $a=1$ then $a^n = 1$ is constant.  If $0 < a < 1$ then $a^n$ is decreasing.

For any $b > 0$ and $a>0; a\ne 1$, there will exist a unique integer $n$ so that $a^{n-1} \le b < a^n$ if $a > 1$ and $a^n < b \le a^{n-1}$ if $a < 1$.

Either way $0 \le |b-a^{n-1}| < |a^n - a^{n-1}|$ or put colloquially, $b$ is between $a^{n-1}$ (inclusively) and $a^n$ (exclusively).

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $a>1$, the function $f(x)=a^x$ is *strictly increasing* function.

Now consider the sequence of sets, $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ with $A_n=[a^{n-1},a^n)$.

Two important thing to note:

1. $A_n$ are disjoint (since $f(x)$ is *strictly increasing* function).
2. $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} A_n=$Range of $f\space=\space\mathbb{R}^{+}=$ the set positive real numbers.

Since $b>0$ and because of 1 and 2 we can easily conclude $a^{n-1}≤b<a^n$ (if not then $b$ can not be positive real number!)

**Why 1 is true?** since $f(x)$ is *strictly increasing* function, $a^n$ are not equal for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Why 2 is true?** Note that we can cover any interval using finite union of the set $A_n$, (say $A_{n_1},A_{n_2},\dots, A_{n_k}$, $k\geq 1$).

(Do not take the word *cover* in tough sense if you don't know mathematical meaning; think of it's proper English meaning, that is enough here!)